# Where do I purchase a Cuba Tourist Card at the Miami International Airport?

Tags: visas, american-airlines, cuba, mia

I will be traveling to Cuba next month using the 'Support For the Cuban People' category. After doing some research, I've found I will need to purchase a Tourist Card from either online or at a kiosk at the airport.

So, my question is:

Where do I find the kiosk in the airport to purchase the Tourist Card? I'm not sure if there will be clear directions/instructions on where to get this.

**Edit**

I do have an inquiry to American Airlines on twitter, and Miami International Airport on Facebook to see if I can get answers.

Comment: Have you tried asking the airline you’re flying with?

Comment: I have an inquiry with them as well. I just know this site is sometimes faster ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received a response from Miami International and they said:

[image]

So, <s>it appears the kiosk will be near the gates</s> it appears you have to leave the terminal, get your Visa (Tourist Card), and then go through security:

[image]

As I receive more information, I will update this answer.

**UPDATE**

I did end up pre-purchasing a tourist cart (just to be on the safe side)

When arriving in Miami, I did not need to leave the terminal and go through security again. While at the gate, they did have a kiosk documentation check, but I was unable to verify if they had the tourist cards there.

When I got in line the lady verified my documents before I could get to the kiosk. Other people were up at the desk filling out paperwork, so they may have had them there.

So, word of advice, get your tourist card before you go. Just to be safe.

Comment: They make it sound like some shady activity where you need to get a pre-paid $100 VISA card which you then hand to someone who then slips you your Cuban Tourist Card. lol

Comment: Right!! In reality, that's probably what it is ;)

Comment: Please update your question with actual experience after the fact!

Comment: I will for sure do that. I leave next month, so it will be a while. With the lack of information about it, I'm sure it will be useful

Comment: In MIA, the kiosk is literally beside to the AA stand, approximately on door #7 where AA make the check-in for Cuba flights. Before to make the check-in ask to an AA attendant where to buy the visa, and they will guide you trough the process. Just remember to have clear how you should be in one of twelve categories allowed to travel to cuba.  check info in this link https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/international-travel/cuba.jsp

Comment: @EmilioGort is this at the gate or outside of the terminal where you have to go through security again?

Comment: That's is before security...outside...

Comment: @EmilioGort Thank you for this additional information

Comment: if you are making a connection clarify that when you contact an AA or a MIA representative trough email or twitter, not sure if there are kiosks after security